# Combining more than one piece of data in a cell. sql

Tags: sql, sql-server

This is for a Homework assignment, but I want to go a step farther.
Let me show my Tables then I'll ask my question.

```
Table -- Students         
StudentID PK, LastName, FirstName, 

Table -- Courses 
 CourseID PK, CourseName

Table -- Registrations 
StudentID FK, CourseID FK
```

The question is How can I add more than one CourseName in that specific cell? For Example I have one student who is taking 3 classes, can I show all 3 CourseNames for that particular student in the same cell in the same row?

```
Example.......

123456,     Smith,     John,  English, Math, Science
```

Sorry if this seems simplistic but I just can't find what I'm looking for after searching.

Comment: I'm using Database Management Studio by the way.

Comment: Bad idea to store that way. You should be storing multiple rows with the same key value to identify the student and one row for each course

Comment: I don't want to store it that way.

Comment: Then why do you need a RDBMS? That way of storing is against the basic principles of an RDBMS

Comment: I just want to write a query that shows those CourseNames linked to the student, or Show all the students via LastName in that specific course.

Comment: And it's called a `column` in a relational database, not a "*cell*". A relational database is *not* a spreadsheet.

Answer (score 0):

You don't put them into 1 cell.
It will be 3 rows. An example will make this a bit more clear:

- John Smith: ID 1025
- Math ID 2500
- English ID 2585
- Violin ID 3250

In your database you will get the following rows:

- StudentID CourseID
- 1025 2500
- 1025 2585
- 1025 3250

Comment: This the code so far but gives all rows, I guess it isn't best practice to limit it SELECT StudentID, LastName, FirstName, CourseName
FROM Students
 JOIN
 Registrations
 ON Students.StudentID = Registrations.StudentID
 JOIN 
 Courses
 ON Courses.CourseID = Registrations.CourseID
ORDER BY LastName;

Answer (score 0):

Well in the spirit of Christmas you can always imagine it's a turkey and STUFF it..

```
DECLARE @Students TABLE(StudentID INT, LastName VARCHAR(50), FirstName VARCHAR(50))
DECLARE @Courses TABLE(CourseID INT, CourseName  VARCHAR(50))
DECLARE @Registrations TABLE(StudentID INT, CourseID INT)

INSERT INTO @Students VALUES
(123456, 'John', 'Smith'),(123457, 'Adrian', 'Sullivan'),(123458, 'Dude', 'Guy')

INSERT INTO @Courses VALUES
(1,'English'),(2,'Math'),(3,'Science')

INSERT INTO @Registrations VALUES
(123456,1),(123456,2),(123456,3),(123457,1),(123457,2),(123458,3)

DECLARE @STID INT
SELECT *,  STUFF((SELECT ','+C2.CourseName
              FROM  @Registrations R2
              INNER JOIN @Courses C2 ON C2.CourseID = R2.CourseID
              WHERE R2.StudentID = S.StudentID
              FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value('.', 'nvarchar(max)'), 1, 1, '') [AllText]
FROM @Students S
```

For more reading on [STUFF](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188043.aspx)